# Fetch the title of map dropped pin via MKPointAnnotation

Tags: ios, dictionary, title, pins, mkpointannotation

I need to know how to fetch the title of a dropped pin. I have multiple dropped pins on the map, when the pin is tabbed I want to fetch the title to pass to `prepareForSegue`. I use this statement "let title = self.pointAnnotation.title" via (`MKPointAnnotation`) but I get the title of the last dropped pin and not the tabbed pin.

Answer (score 0):

An easy and reliable way to get a reference to the annotation that was tapped is to use the map view's selectedAnnotations array: if let ann = self.mapView.selectedAnnotations[0] as? MKAnnotation {
        println("(ann.title!)")
    }